# Flask-SocketIO redis subscribe

Tags: python, flask, redis

I'm using https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO to implement a WebSocket server.

I need to receive a message from another process (only subscribe) and emit for clients in a specific room.

But, when i try to send the message, i got this error:

> Could not send message to home room: Working outside of request context.

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, send, rooms
import json
import eventlet
import logging
import redis
import threading

FORMAT = '%(asctime)-15s - %(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app, async_mode='eventlet')

.
.
.

def _send_task_message():
    try:
        send(json.dumps({"type":"UPDATE_TASK"}), room='home')
    except Exception as e:
        log.error('Could not send message to home room: %s' % str(e)) 

class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, r, channels):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.redis = r
        self.pubsub = self.redis.pubsub()
        self.pubsub.psubscribe(channels)

    def work(self, item):
        if isinstance(item['data'], bytes):
            try:
                msg = item['data'].decode('utf-8')
                decode_msg = json.loads(msg)                
                if decode_msg['type'] == 'UPDATE_TASK':
                    _send_task_message()
            except ValueError as e:
                log.error("Error decoding msg to microservice: %s", str(e))

    def run(self):
        for item in self.pubsub.listen():
            self.work(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    r = redis.Redis()
    client = Listener(r, ['/bobguarana/socketio'])
    client.start()

    socketio.run(debug=True, app=app, port=8080)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Solved passing the app as an argument to the class and using it context as suggested by the error description, but the namespace is necessary too:

```
class Listener(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, r, channels, app):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.daemon = True
    self.redis = r
    self.pubsub = self.redis.pubsub()
    self.pubsub.psubscribe(channels)
    self.app = app

    def work(self, item):
        with app.app_context():
            if isinstance(item['data'], bytes):
                try:
                    msg = item['data'].decode('utf-8')
                    decode_msg = json.loads(msg)                
                    if decode_msg['type'] == 'UPDATE_TASK':
                        send(json.dumps({"type":"UPDATE_TASK"}), room='home', namespace='/')
                    #_send_task_message()
                except ValueError as e:
                    log.error("Error decoding msg to microservice: %s", str(e))

    def run(self):
        for item in self.pubsub.listen():
            self.work(item)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    r = redis.Redis()
    client = Listener(r, ['/bobguarana/socketio'], app)
    client.start()

    socketio.run(debug=True, app=app, port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

[If you look at the source code of the flask_socketio.send method](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/blob/master/flask_socketio/__init__.py#L738), you can see that if namespace is omitted, flask_socketio will try to get it from a current request. But when you receive a message from your redis, there wouldn't be any current request to get the namespace from. So in order to send socketio messages without current request (which is called the `request context` in Flask), you should specify a namespace ('/' is by default, IIRC):

```
send(json.dumps({"type":"UPDATE_TASK"}), room='home', namespace='/')
```

Comment: It did not work.
Working outside of request context.

"This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information."

I will try to investigate about it.